# Postfix - Connection Refused error

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to build send only mail server using postfix. I folowed this [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) from digital ocean

When I try to send email, it gives below error. (I copied from /var/log/mail.log)

lets say my domain name is `domainaddress.com`

```
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/qmgr[22091]: B22861BA03A: from=<hsntngr@domainaddress>, size=403, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26332]: connect to domainaddress[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26333]: connect to domainaddress[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26332]: 6A8D81BA0FA: to=<hsntngr@domainaddress>, relay=none, delay=29909, delays=29909/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (conn$
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26332]: connect to domainaddress.com[128.199.50.100]:25: Connection refused
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26333]: 6CDC81BA03F: to=<hsntngr@domainaddress>, relay=none, delay=126295, delays=126295/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (co$
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26332]: 6BDFF1BA0F8: to=<hsntngr@domainaddress.com>, relay=none, delay=29997, delays=29997/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred ($
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26333]: connect to domainaddress[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused
Feb  9 07:52:54 domainaddress postfix/smtp[26333]: B22861BA03A: to=<your_email_address@domainaddress>, relay=none, delay=126304, delays=126304/0.02/0.01/0, dsn=4.4.1, status..
```

Even if I setup my host name in config file, host name seems wrong..

Also my config file (/etc/postfix/main.cf)

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.domainaddress.com
mydomain = domainaddress.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, $mydomain , www.$mydomain    
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

I know I'm doing something wrong at somewhere but I couldn't figure out what it is and where, for two days.

Answer (score 4):

As [Freddy](https://serverfault.com/users/505837/freddy) points in a comment, ensure you don’t have unapplied changes by restarting postfix:

```
service postfix restart
```

If the issue persists, add a row in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 mail.domainaddress.com
```

Also ensure you can resolve hostnames

```
nslookup google.com
```

otherwise, fix it starting from what you have in your network configuration file.

Ensure that your firewall isn’t blocking localhost:25

```
telent localhost 25
```

should not return timeout/refused, otherwise

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Those rules **will** allow the connection despite anything you might have in your firewall configuration, **but that’s just a bad workaround**. It might skip any security relying on your firewall logs, for instance.

If the firewall is the case, avoid permanently saving those rules, and start a full review of your iptables ruleset instead.

Reading your logs there is no doubt that postfix is running. Other users coming into this issue might have different/no logs and same symptoms and thus, if they didn’t restart postfix yet, it might be worth for them **before editing their iptables ruleset** to run also:

```
service postfix status
```

and if it’s not running

```
service postfix start
```

Comment: I can resolve hostnames but you're right something wrong while resolving localhost:25. I tried to your solution but it throwed Bad argument `—dport' ..

Comment: It seems my mobile is fixing two - in one — that is a different character. You should input minus minus dport with no spaces.

Comment: thanks, now I'm able to get 220 mail.domainaddress.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu). But still gives connection refused error while sending email. btw something get my attention. it says `domainaddress[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused`.. not domainaddress.com or mail.domainaddress.com just domainaddress. But I filled my hostname properly in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is something wrong about this ?

Comment: I think that you’d better start over, searching for this new issue, double checking every step from the how to and if you can’t find old questions with same issue start a new one. Probably it is related to your postfix configuration file or to your server’s dns hostname host file setup.

Comment: I'll consider this. Well actually that one is my second try but it might be better to start over. thanks for your help and advices

Comment: If you just changed your hostname, then restart postfix.

Comment: @Freddy unapplied settings... I didn’t consider that. Well put.

Comment: @HasanTıngır by start over, I mean start over troubleshooting this new issue!

Comment: @Marco ops I might be misunderstand that little :) well that is my last option actually,  I believe if I solve this incorrect host name issue it might be work

Comment: @Freddy I always restarts prefix after changing something.. But still uses incorrect hostname.. actually that hostname coming from dpkg confifuration, it shouldn't be problem

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that port 25 is blocked preventing connections to external smtps (probably by your ISP)? I guess `telnet mail.domainaddress.com 25` also fails? Can you try that?

Comment: it says `could not resolve mail.domainaddress.com/25: No address associated with hostname`. But I created mx record for that ?

Comment: You can also use the ip address instead of the host name.